# What do the curly braces mean in an import statement?

Tags: typescript

In the TypeScript handbook, in the section [Shorthand Ambient Modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#shorthand-ambient-modules), it shows an import statement like this:

```
import x, {y} from "hot-new-module";
```

Nowhere does it explain why `y` in the above statement is in curly braces. If both `x` and `y` were inside the braces (i.e. `import {x, y} from...`) then it probably wouldn't have caught my eye - but now I'm wondering why one is inside and not the other.

What do the braces actually signify? How would you choose which things to put in braces?

Comment: Curly braces signify the export type, which is a named export. This is different from default exports, the other type. The difference is named exports allow for aliasing the package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*TL;DR*

What goes between braces are the named exports.

Here is a classic one:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
```

This imports the whole module under the `React` name, so you could access `Component` using `React.Component`.

But to make code shorter and clearer, the named export `Component` is also imported under its name so it can be used directly without the `React` namespace prefix

That syntax should be equivalent to

```
import {default as React, Component, PropTypes} from 'react'
```

Final note: you can actually rename on import

```
import {Component as TheComponent} from 'react'
```

n.b: the need to import `React` is a "limitation" of the JSX compiler